# Translate to GTiff from NOAA nc file

Tags: qgis, gdal, r, netcdf, noaa

I have level 2 of NOAA nc file. The data is in https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjXAWS5maHffhyqaxqd61ok-SFsY?e=mcUdnE.
I want to open the file in QGIS or GRASS GIS. But, they don't recognize it. So, I use GDAL.
I get it from gdalinfo :

```
$ gdalinfo noaa19_L2_d20210102_t2309066_e2319520_c20210102124945585006_iapp.nc
Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: noaa19_L2_d20210102_t2309066_e2319520_c20210102124945585006_iapp.nc
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
NC_GLOBAL#End_Scan_Line_DOY=0
NC_GLOBAL#End_Scan_Line_Time=0
NC_GLOBAL#End_Scan_Line_Year=0
NC_GLOBAL#IAPP_Version_Number=4
NC_GLOBAL#Satellite_Name=noaa19
NC_GLOBAL#Start_Scan_Line_DOY=0
NC_GLOBAL#Start_Scan_Line_Time=0
NC_GLOBAL#Start_Scan_Line_Year=0
Subdatasets:
SUBDATASET_1_NAME=NETCDF:"noaa19_L2_d20210102_t2309066_e2319520_c20210102124945585006_iapp.nc":Latitude
SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[0x18] Latitude (32-bit floating-point)
...
...
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

Then I want to translate to GTiff. But, it is error.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff NETCDF:"noaa19_L2_d20210102_t2309066_e2319520_c20210102124945585006_iapp.nc":Surface_Temperature test.tiff
Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Input file size is 18, 0
ERROR 1: Error: -srcwin 0 0 18 0 has negative width and/or height.
```

Then I try to use gdalwarp. But, it is still error.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:"noaa19_L2_d20210102_t2309066_e2319520_c20210102124945585006_iapp.nc":Surface_Temperature test.tiff
Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
ERROR 1: The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed for NETCDF:noaa19_L2_d20210102_t2309066_e2319520_c20210102124945585006_iapp.nc:Surface_Temperature. There is no affine transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypass this check.
```

I also try SeaDAS. The message : No appropriate reader found.

I also try R. It is from https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_way_to_convert_nc_files_into_tif_files. It is error.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
fname <- file.choose()
nc<-nc_open(fname)
PCP <- brick(fname, varname="Surface_Temperature")
writeRaster(PCP, filename="sst.tif", format="GTiff",overwrite=TRUE)
```

Error in the step:

```
PCP <- brick(fname, varname="Surface_Temperature")
[1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named Across_Track BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
[1] "vobjtovarid4: **** WARNING **** I was asked to get a varid for dimension named Along_Track BUT this dimension HAS NO DIMVAR! Code will probably fail at this point"
Error in .rasterObjectFromCDF(x, type = objecttype, band = band, ...) :
cells are not equally spaced; you should extract values as points
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(rs) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(rs) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(rs) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

So, how to export to GTiff, so I can open in GRASS or QGIS ?

Comment: I do not believe that that data can be converted into GeoTIFF. GeoTIFF has two dimensions, width and height, but that subdataset seems to be one-dimensional [0x18]. Conversion of Land_Ocean_Index fails also even it has more dimensions [0x9x18] with a message `Warning 1: Several 1D variables are indexed by dimension Along_Track Input file size is 9, 18
ERROR 1: test.tif: Unable to export GeoTIFF files with zero bands.`. It seems that you need some other tools for handling this kind of NetCDF.

Comment: Do you know the tool for handling this kind of NetCDF?

Comment: No, I don't, but search `netcdf+tools` gives many hits, for example https://nsidc.org/data/netcdf/tools.html.